# What can be the best approach to store 2D array of Objects?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I want to store C++ objects in MxN table, and I want to create the Object like:

```
Vector2D<MyObject*> objects = new Vector2D<MyObject*>(M,N);
MyObject* obj = new MyObject;
objects.add(i,j, obj);
```

And later on, I should access the items in similar way.
Please suggest me the best ideas, not just the ways. I know few of them. :)

EDIT:
Basically what i need is, Just allocate memory for MxN grid of generic Object. Just add/retrieve the items with the given row and Column.

Comment: `MyObject obj = new MyObject;` does not compile.

Comment: Do you want to create them on the stack or on the heap?

Comment: This is a meaningless question unless you give some idea of what 'best' means for you.

Comment: I see you've edited the question. Now you are trying to program C++ like it was Java. C++ is not Java, trying to pretend that it is will get you sub-optimal programs at best and a whole heap of pain at worst. There's no way that this approach can be considered a 'best idea'.

Comment: @john this can be a good way for sparse matrix. except for the initial new Vector2D.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you came from Java or C# world in C++ realm. Welcome. In C++ you have automatic storage object and you don't have to `new` everything. This is enough if you also have `Vector2D` class.

```
Vector2D<MyObject> objects(M,N);
MyObject obj;
objects.add(i,j, obj);
```

Otherwise you can make a 2D vector by [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<std::vector<MyObject>> objects;
```

Comment: Yes I'm from java background. The problem now is I need Vector2D class.I'm asking what can be better way to implementing it.

Comment: @dg_no_9: I've written a sample by `std::vector`.

Comment: Anything wrong with implementing it using `std::vector<std::vector<MyObject>>?` It's the *straightforward* way. You're still not saying what best means for you.

Comment: What if I want to make generic Vector2D container which can store any type of objects?

Comment: @dg_no_9 Templates can store any type of object. If you mean a Vector2D can *simultaneously* store different types of object, then there are lots of ways to do that depending on precisely what your requirements are.

Comment: @dg_no_9 Do you want to store a) literally any type, use `boost::any`, b) various unrelated types from a fixed list, use `boost::variant`, c) various related types, use polymorphism and `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @dg_no_9 with vectors you can access an element like `objects[i][j]`. @M M. you should add this info as OP is new to c++, stl

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is:

```
vector<vector<MyObject>> objects ;
```

Unfortunately you will have to write some code to initialize each row to size N.

There is a good lecture on the microsoft channel9 site where Stephan T. Lavavej (yes his initials are STL) does exactly this for solving the nurikabe puzzle.

[C9 - STL lecture - Nurikabe solver](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-4-of-n)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a 2D vector. Reference: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<std::vector<MyObject>> objects;
```

But before using this object you should have made this object.

```
// you know the size of your 2D : MaxRow, MaxCol
std::vector<std::vector<MyObject> > objects(MaxRow, 
                               std::vector<MyObject>(MaxCol, MyObject());
```

Or you can

```
std::vector<std::vector<MyObject> > objects;
for(size_t r_i=0; r_i<MaxRow; ++r_i) {
      // create and push a row in the 2D matrix.
      objects.push_back(std::vector<MyObject>());
      for(size_t c_i=0; c_i<MaxCol; ++c_i) {
           // push a col in the new created row.
           objects[r_i].push_back(MyObject());
      }
 }
```

Now you want to access your matrix.

```
size_t row, col;
// now you know your row and col : input or from anywhere
```

Lets say that you have a function `callObject` in `MyObject` class.

```
// you can do this.
objects[row][col].callObject();
```

---

But if you want to store sparse matrices, then you can do

```
std::vector<std::vector<MyObject*>objects(MaxRow, 
                           std::vector<MyObject>(MaxCol, nullptr);
objects[2][3] = new MyObject(/*your arguments*/);

objects[2][3].callObject();

objects[0][0].callObject(); // Boom !!! Null pointer here.
```

With Pointers use, [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

---

If you want a Vector2D class you can use it wrap around this vector of vectors.

```
 typedef MyObject T;
 class Vector2D {
      std::vector<std::vector<T> > objects;
      public:
      // initialize the objects with MaxRow rows each with MaxCol cols.
      Vector2D(size_t MaxRow, size_t MaxCol);
      // remember that there should already be somebody at this row or col
      // or you have to create all the rows before this row and all the cols before
      // this col in this row.
      void addItem(size_t row, size_t col, const MyObject & obj);   
 };
```

I used `typedef int T` because it would be easier for changing to templates.

---

As i said before, it depends a lot on what you want and your data is. if its kind of sparse, i would have used vector of vector of pointers.

```
 typedef MyObject T;
 class Vector2D {
      std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T> > > objects;
      public:
      // initialize the Nullptr with MaxRow rows each with MaxCol cols.
      Vector2D(size_t MaxRow, size_t MaxCol);
      // now you can just add the item, as pointer is already there.
      void addItem(size_t row, size_t col, MyObject * obj);   
 };
```

Using unique_ptr as it takes care of deletion and other referencing things.

---

You could have "got a lot of other things" by inheriting `std::vector< std::vector<T> >` in Vector2D, but composition is better than inheritance in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, It seems good way. I'll just try it out. :)

Comment: What can be the better way to implement addItem(row, col, MyObject) functionality in your way?

Comment: @dg_no_9 If your class MyObject size is small, then using vector<vector<MyObject>> with initial filling of matrix with dummy MyObjects would be OK. but if its big, then i would consider using vector of vector of pointers. And then you can make a function addItem.

Answer (score 0):

better you use array of STRUCT, the field of STRUCT depends on what kind of your MyObject's field

Answer (score 0):

I would create a vector of vectors and overload all the needed operators. So you can reuse the std implementation. 
But first of all think about, how you want to access this Vector2D. Is it really a vector or is an other storeage type better.

Comment: I just want to access the 2d array with row, col index. For e.g. array.getObj(row, col);

Answer (score 0):

With a modern C++11 compiler you can use the built in `array` and `initializer_lists` and it would look something like this:

```
    #include <array>
    using namespace std;
    ...

    vector<vector<int>> Objects;

    // Initialization
    Objects = {{1,2,3}, {4,4,5}};
    // Iterating
    for ( auto it = Objects.begin(); it != Objects.end(); ++it) {
      // you can access the arrays with *it in here
      for( auto it2 = *it->begin(); it2 != *it->end(); ++it2) {
        // you can access values directly with *it2
        *it2 = 1;
      }
    }
```

You can use auto and let the compiler figure out the type as I did or you can specify that `it` and `it2` are in fact vector iterators.